# Export comments from fb:comments

Tags: comments, facebook-fql

I'm a little desperate about this. I have a site with a comments box with around 183000 comments that I want to backup. But every time I do an fql.query, I only get 100 items. I had tried:

```
SELECT xid, object_id, post_id, time, text, id FROM comment WHERE   xid='bdatapoyo' ORDER BY time DESC
```

and after that, using the last "time"

```
SELECT xid, object_id, post_id, time, text, id FROM comment WHERE   xid='bdatapoyo' AND time >= xxxxxxx ORDER BY time DESC
```

but the latter only gives me one comment..

I made an PHP page with this code, but again, it only grabs 100 items:

```
<?php        
    require 'php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
    'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
    'cookie' => true,
    ));

    $conexion = mysql_connect("localhost", "XXXX", "XXXX");
    mysql_select_db("TVN", $conexion);

    $time_old = "1315070888";
    do {

        $fql = "SELECT fromid,time,text FROM comment WHERE xid='bdatapoyo' AND time >= " . $time_old . " ORDER BY time";

        $response = $facebook->api(array(
            'method' => 'fql.query',
            'query' =>$fql,
        ));

        foreach($response as $key => $value) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO comment (text, uuid, time) VALUES ('" . $value["text"] . "', '" . $value["fromid"] . "', '" . $value["time"] . "')";     
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
        }

        $time_old = $response[count($response)-1]["time"];
        print_r($time_old);
    } while (count($response) > 0);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, I was able to pull this out with LIMIT and OFFSET. The correct FQL is

```
SELECT fromid,time,text FROM comment WHERE xid='bdatapoyo' LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

and then paging with the OFFSET

Answer (score 0):

is this code setup to import every single comment to a db from all users on your site? What is xid=bdatapoyo?